# how make kafkajs read only header without consuming the message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apache-kafka

I'm using npm kafkajs to consume messages.
I want to check message header only without consuming it?
My consumer has `autoCommit: true` option.
Should I add second consumer with `autoCommit: false` ?
Or there is other way to read just message header while base consumer can read/get whole message?

I need to check some messages state for other process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The headers are not stored externally to the record, so each record must be consumed, even if that means you skip key/record deserialization.

https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/1584

Commits are unrelated to the issue; you can choose to enable them or not.